# addClass, removeClass, css jquery functions does not work

Tags: jquery, html

I found [this page](http://www.windsorbrokers.biz/prices/live_ticker_en.php) and I need to change the font color from black to white.

I tried these ways but they did not work:

1. jquery add class function (to add class to SPAN tag)
2. jquery remove class function(to remove the class scrollingNews from MARQUEE tag)
3. jquery css function (to add css to SPAN tag)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

  $('#tickerV span').addClass('test');
  $('marquee').removeClass('scrollingNews')  
  $('#tickerV span').css({color: white});

});
```

Please can you help?
Thanks

Comment: Show us the code and we will tell you why it didn't work. Also that page is.. blank?

Comment: Thanks for your fast replay, it's not empty there is marquee at the top.

Comment: You need to quote your 'white' (`'white'`)

Comment: Are you trying to load that page, into your own page within an iframe? You can't manipulate content in an iframe, that is not on your domain.

Comment: yes i'm using iframe to do that, can j query do what i need?

Comment: No unfortunately not, look at my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('span').css({ 'color': 'red'});
```

Comment: yes there some span tags changed to red, but not the one i want

Comment: do you have specific id or class for that spam

Comment: For all the span inside the marquee

Comment: ok add a new class for that morque and then add css in ur stylesheet and the write which color u want i that css and mark it as important the ur problem will be solved

Comment: It's not working, for the reason that i gave in my answer, and it will never work. You should accept my answer. (:

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that if the content of the iframe is on the same domain, running same protocol and on the same port. And i highly doubt that it is, then you wouldn't load it in an iframe.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript